navbar-nav dropdown-item dropdown-toggle not displaying submenu items
I have this menu that is driving me crazy:
<!-- inside/menu.html -->
<div class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
    <!-- File Dropdown -->
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="fileDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            File
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="fileDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="moreHelpDropdown">More Help</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="moreHelpDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FAQ</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Support</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

This looks great but I am having a couple of issues...

I would really like the arrow next to "More Help" to point to the right instead of down.
When I click "More Help" the open menu closes and nothing is displayed.

Here is my menu.css file:
/* menu.css */
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-item.management-company {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.bold-disabled {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6c757d;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    content: ''; /* No arrow for top-level dropdowns */
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-toggle::after {
    content: '\25B6'; /* Rightward arrow */
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 1rem; /* Match the size of other arrows */
}

I've changed to bootstrap 5 with no css and it works beautifully, but I want the Security and Help menus on the right of the page and File on the left:
<!-- inside/menu.html -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <!-- File -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">File</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Corporate &raquo; </a>
                                <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                                    {% if management_companies | length > 1 %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/select_management_company">Select Company</a></li>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Select Company</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if default_management_company == "" %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Edit Company</a></li>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/edit_management_company">Edit Company</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if allow_more_management_companies %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Add Company</a></li>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/new_management_company">Add Company</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if default_management_company == "" %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Delete Company</a></li>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/delete_management_company">Delete Company</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 3 </a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 4 </a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <!-- Security -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Security </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/authentication">Authentication</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/change_password">Change password</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Help -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Help </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/help">Help</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(function(element){
            element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
              e.stopPropagation();
            });
        })
        if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
            document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .dropdown').forEach(function(everydropdown){
                everydropdown.addEventListener('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
                    // after dropdown is hidden, then find all submenus
                      this.querySelectorAll('.submenu').forEach(function(everysubmenu){
                        // hide every submenu as well
                        everysubmenu.style.display = 'none';
                      });
                })
            });

            document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu a').forEach(function(element){
                element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

                    let nextEl = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if(nextEl && nextEl.classList.contains('submenu')) {
                        // prevent opening link if link needs to open dropdown
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log(nextEl);
                        if(nextEl.style.display == 'block'){
                            nextEl.style.display = 'none';
                        } else {
                            nextEl.style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    });
</script>

I've done this for now.  I know it is a terrible solution, but I am desparate :-/
    <!-- Security and Help Dropdowns -->
<ul class="navbar-nav" style="margin-left: 30rem;">
    <!-- Security Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Security </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <!-- Security dropdown items -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/authentication">Authentication</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/change_password">Change password</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- Help Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Help </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <!-- Help dropdown items -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/help">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

I'm trying to add something like this to center some text on the menu, but this is not working for me either<div class="navbar-nav"
style="text-align: center">
            <span class="nav-link bold-disabled">{{ username }} PropMan: {{ default_management_company }}</span>
        </div>


I've changed to bootstrap 5 with no css and it works beautifully, but I want the Security and Help menus on the right of the page and File on the left (code is above)

I added  which has masked the problem, but it's the best I can figure out.  Coded added above

I'm trying to add some text that is centered on the menu with         
